# Who is this character shown on the Video Games The Movie movie poster?

Tags: game-identification

On this movie poster for [Video Games The Movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3214002/), a documentary about the history of video games, I am able to recognize most of the iconic characters shown. Yet, there is that one character with a hat looking like an explorer that I am not able to recognize. Who is this character?

[image]

Comment: I tried reverse image search through multiple engines.  I'm not getting anything!  I think someone in marketing drew it or something...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's [Pitfall Harry](http://pitfall.wikia.com/wiki/Pitfall_Harry) from the [Pitfall!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitfall!) games.

This one with the green shirt, hat, and no jacket is specifically from the mobile endless runner version.

[image]
[image]

He has gone through a lot of different versions...
[image]
[image]
[image]